# How can I pass a file/file path from one Button_Click event to another in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, file

I have a fileupload control (FileUpload1) in my webform which I use to load an excel file. I use a button called btn_open to display it in a gridview on click.
I also save the file using FileUpload1.SaveAs() method in a server folder.

Now I have another button called btn_edit which on click needs to use the same
file that I just loaded to do another set of operations.

How do I pass this file/file path from btn_open_Click to btn_edit_Click? I do not want to specify the exact location on the code. There will be multiple times I will open new excel files so I don't want to specify the file path to the server for every new file.This needs to happen programatically. Also, I want to avoid using Interop if its possible.

The following code snippet might make things more clear as to what I want to do.

```
protected void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
         if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".xlsx" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".xls")
            {
                string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);      //capture the file name of the file I have uploaded
                path = path.Replace(" ", "");                              // if there is any spacing between the file name it will remove it 
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path); //saves to Server folder called ExcelFile
                String ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path; // Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path. 
                    .   
                    .
                    *code to display it in gridview*
                    .
                    .
               }
            else
                {
                      Console.Writeline("File type not permissible");
                }
   }

protected void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    //HOW DO I PASS THE ABOVE FILE HERE PROGRAMATICALLY WITHOUT SPECIFYING IT'S EXACT LOCATION ON THE SERVER??

    }
```

Comment: Can you put the file path you just saved in ~/ExcelFile/ folder into view state? That will be available upon postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Session variable helped me solve my problem. Hopefully it will be helpful to other people who might encounter similar issue.

On the first button (in my case btn_open_Click), add:

```
Session["myXlsPath"] = ExcelFilePath;
```

Note: "myXlsPath" is just a name I created for my Session variable. ExcelFilePath  is the path of my excel file that I want to pass to the other button.

On the button you want to pass the file path to (in my case btn_edit_Click), add:

```
string ExcelFilePath = (string)Session["myXlsPath"];
```